# How to select option using Model?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Didn't found a thing about this.

I have a model:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string No { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public string FilterStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have second thing:

```
<select id="status" name="status" style="width: 120px;font-size: 0.9em; padding: 0;" class="k-dropdown">
    <option>-- Select --</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>
```

The thing I am trying to do is to select option, which is equal with Model.FilterStatus. For example, if Status is 'Yes', then text in dropdown should be 'Yes'. But is there possible way to do it? With javascript or not?

Comment: Why not use `@Html.DropdownFor()`so its binds correctly?

Comment: Also I am using FormCollection in my controller. I guess I cant send data from dropdown there. (And also i am a big newbie in mvc).

Comment: Edit your question and put complete code so we can understand situation i.e. `Controller` class with `Action` method code (MVC parts) because IMO `FormCollection` is used only when its http `POST` and its used in `Action` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Html.DropDown helper. This helper gets an IEnumerable with the options you show.
In your controller you can send the values for your dropdown in the ViewBag or using a View Model. This property of your view model has to be a List with SelectListItem(s) with your two options Yes and No, then using the value of your filter to select the right option like this:

```
ViewBag.Status = new List<SelectListItem>(){
     new SelectListItem
     {
        Value = "Yes",
        Text = "Yes",
        Selected = yourFilter.FilterStatus  //If your status is Yes this will be true 
                                            //otherwise false.
     },
     new SelectListItem
     {
        Value = "No",
        Text = "No",
        Selected = yourFilter.FilterStatus  //If your status is No this will be true 
                                            //otherwise false.
     }
};
```

Then on your view you can print your dropdown list using the Html helper:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Status", "--Select--")
```

Using ViewBag be careful that the name of the property has to match the name on the helper and this is going to be the same name that the form will send back to the controller when submiting the form.

If you used the View Model version, that I recommend you for testing purposes you have to create that view model and assign the dropdown values to that property, something like this:

```
//Don't create this class on the controller! This is only as an example.
public class FilterViewModel {
   public bool Status {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statusDropDown {get; set;}
}

var myViewModel = new FilterViewModel();
myViewModel.statusDropDown = new List<SelectListItem>(){
     new SelectListItem
     {
        Value = "Yes",
        Text = "Yes",
        Selected = yourFilter.FilterStatus
     },
     new SelectListItem
     {
        Value = "No",
        Text = "No",
        Selected = yourFilter.FilterStatus
     }
};

return View(myViewModel);
```

And you could use the following helper on your view:

```
@model Controllers.YourController.FilterViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, Model.statusDropDown, "--Select--")
```

Comment: Added a little changes but this example works almost fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@model Filter

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FilterStatus, new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem> { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "Yes" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "No" }  
    }, "Value", "Text"), 
    "--- Select Option ---", new { @class = "k-dropdown" })
```

Comment: Thanks for such fast answer, but I have additional one. Maybe sounds stupid, but, how will it works? I mean, right now selected from my dropdown are used in FormCollection. And as I see, this version cant be used like that.

Comment: Of course it can, but why use FormCollection and not your model so its already bound (e.g. `[HttpPost](public ActionResult YourAction(Filter model){...`)

Comment: It can? How? For example right now I use collection["status"] to get selected option, but id is needed, or I can do something similar to new { @class = "k-dropdown", @Id= "status"} ? HttpPost... that the reason. Will try it now.

Comment: check [THIS](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) example